# UIWebView link to local files without setting the baseURL to the app directory

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a web view in an app loading an html snippet from a server which includes text and images. I'm wrapping that in a little html and putting it into a web view like this:

```
NSString *cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];

NSString *cssLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<link href='file://%@/' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>", cssPath];

NSString *html = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><title></title><meta charset='UTF-8' />%@</head><body>%@</body></html>", cssLink, htmlContent] retain];

[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:currentURL];
```

Is there any way to fix the above code so that the link to the local stylesheet works?

I could load the stylesheet without problem if I change the base url to the local application resources file, but this breaks the image links within the html loaded from the server.

I could also include the contents of the stylesheet directly into the html, but would prefer not to do that for a number of reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

What is `currentURL`? It should be `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]`, e.g.

```
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

And I believe the cssPath can be just the filename, instead of the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks! I can do that and it works just fine. However, I'm using html from a different api that contains relative links to images and such, so the baseURL can't be the bundle url.

Is it possible to create an absolue link to a local css file?

Comment: Have you tried `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"style" withExtension:@"css"]`, which return a URL instead of a path?

Comment: That looks like a big step in the right direction. The URL looks correct (file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/67670E71-B8F0-4C99-9FAC-BAF0D6941E87/Wikithing.app/style.css), but the css still doesn't load when I link it in the html. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would try to check two things: whether the css file is readable (i.e. open and read the content of the file, perhaps display it with the UIWebView), and whether the `html` string is well-formed.

Comment: Both seem to be working. I can log the css file loaded from the local url, and if I replace that url with one for a css file online it works fine. Perhaps it's just not possible to do this.

Comment: That's a bit odd. I suppose you may have to inject the content of the CSS file straight into the HTML file then, surrounded by `<style>`.

Comment: This works for me. You can actually debug now with Safari 6 via Develop -> iPhone simulator (show develop menu via advanced preferences), and see what's wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late to help you, Anthony. Sorry! Here's a working solution for any other brave heroes walking the same path:

```
NSString* bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] absoluteString];

NSString* cssString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><base href='%@'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/></head><body>Hi Mom!</body></html>"
                      , bundlePath"];
```

Comment: where should we put the bundlePath ?

Comment: Sorry have added in the missing string token.